# Displaying text file using Javascript and radiobutton

Tags: javascript, html

How can I display 1.txt or 2.txt file in the next page using javascript and radiobutton only.

```html
<input type="radio" name="choice">File 1
<input type="radio" name="choice">File 2<br>
<input type="submit" value="Read"><br>
```

Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score -1):

Assuming these files are in the same folder as you page, a very simple solution would be to do this:

HTML:

```
<input class="myRadio" type="radio" name="choice" value="1.txt">File 1
<input class="myRadio" type="radio" name="choice" value="2.txt">File 2<br>
<input onclick="myFunction()" type="button" value="Read"><br>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(){
    var radios = document.getElementsByClassName('myRadio'); // get array of all radio buttons

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){ // loop through array of radio buttons
        if (radios[i].checked){ // check if current button is checked
            window.location.href = radios[i].value; // simulate clicking a link with button value as href
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, it shows an error, "File was not found." I put the files on the same directory. BTW, thanks.